# Django form how to create a simple mixin

Tags: django, forms, mixins, django-crispy-forms

I have a set of special forms that refer to a single model, I've defined a common:

```
class myBaseFormMixin(forms.Form):    
    data_prod = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today, label='Data')

    class Meta:
     model = mymodel

    def clean(self):
        if self.data["a"]=='off':  
          raise forms.ValidationError("check A")
```

then in my specialform added:

```
class SpecialManForm(forms.ModelForm,myBaseFormMixin)
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SpecialManForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(

            Fieldset(
                'Description',
                Row(
                Div('field_a', css_class='large-3 columns '),
                ),
            ),
```

everything  fine apparently, in the form all fields from the model in  **Meta** Mixin are available but the **clean()** from the mixin isn't executed, it work if I append the **def clean()** to SpecialManForm, why this happen?

Am I missing something? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved with inheritance:

```
class myBaseFormMixin(forms.ModelForm):
```

then the special form :

```
class SpecialManForm(myBaseFormMixin)
```

Comment: So you have an extra class that isn't actually needed now.

Comment: Why would you say that? just one class is used as base for others... so :SpecialManForm -> ModelForm -> myBaseFormMixin, became SpecialManForm -> myBaseFormMixin

Comment: Well you did ask how to use mixins, and that's what my answer showed you how to do.  They effectively accomplish the same thing, but my solution uses less code and creates less classes.

Comment: Thanks for explanataion, I think I should search more in doc to understand which is best, mixin or inheritance. Have a nice day

Comment: If you don't actually plan to create an instance of your myBaseFormMixin, then mixins are probably more appropriate. Though the two approaches are very similar.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your SpecialManForm so that it uses your mixin first.

```
class SpecialManForm(myBaseFormMixin, forms.ModelForm)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ....
```

When python is looking for the clean method, it will first check the SpecialManForm class, where it isn't implemented. It will then go through the inheritance heirarchy, which means checking ModelForm first (as you currently have it). It is implemented there, so it will use the code from ModelForm, rather than from your mixin, and execute that.

Changing the order in the class definition means that it will check your mixin before the ModelForm class for the clean method, and use the method that you have implemented.

It checks (your version) in the following order SpecialManForm -> ModelForm -> myBaseFormMixin, and that explains why it worked when you added the method to the SpecialManForm.